# Using \uncover in latex beamer class with notes

Tags: beamer, overlays, presentations, notes

I am preparing a Latex Beamer presentation with notes and using the uncover option. When I compile the PDF with the "show notes on second screen" option notes only appear for the uncovered last version of a particular slide. I expect the notes to be attached to every version of a slide. Otherwise they are somewhat useless.

I do something like this for every slide:

```
\frame{
    \frametitle{slide} 
    lorem ipsum...

    \uncover<2->{
        surprise!
    }
}

\note{
    do not forget to say this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the note before the frame is finished:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{slide} 
    lorem ipsum...

    \uncover<2->{
        surprise!
    }

    \note{
        do not forget to say this
    }
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Should have figured this out by myself. But thanks!

Comment: @timeinhardt You're welcome!